Updating Apache tomcat 8 to 9 issue
Using java 8 (zulu edition)
Application is in java seam framework (kind a old)
Everything works perfectly fine in Tomcat 8, however when I switch to tomcat 9 either on the server or via intellij I get the following page: attached
enter link description here
intellij logs shows
 java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
 java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
 java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
 java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
 org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:63)
 java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[2024-05-07 11:18:16,396] **Artifact newrecovery:war exploded: Error during artifact deployment. See server log for details.**

server logs Catalina:
07-May-2024 13:14:16.170 WARNING [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [newrecovery] appears to have started a thread named [Catalina-utility-2] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.backgroundProcess(StandardContext.java:5266)
 org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1314)
 org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1318)
 org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1318)
 org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1296)
 java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
 java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
 java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
 java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
 org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:63)
 java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

can someone help please
Additional note:
I did update java servlet from 2.5 to 4.01 (works with tomcat 8 without an issue)
also intellij version is: 2024.1
update:
i enabled loggings more in details now I get this
SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class 

seems like servlet issue with tomcat 9?

I am no expert on this, but that "RMI TCP Connection" is unexpected. I would not expect Tomcat to be using RMI. Is that your code?

Not using remote method in my code @BasilBourque

problem solved, I had to upgrade the javassist.jar to the latest to fix this issue
